# JQuery UI show('slide', {direction: right}, 500) not sliding, just showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to finally put this baby to bed... (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473798/jquery-ui-show-slide-not-working-correctly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485417/jquery-using-no-wrap-in-head-on-actual-site) for context/previous attempts and discussion)

I am trying to hide an element by sliding it to the left/right, and show an element by sliding in from the left or right:

```
$(oldBox).hide('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
$(newBox).show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
```

What actually happens is that the old element hides without sliding, and the new element shows without sliding.

Relevant section(s) of HTML (the same code repeats several times, just has changes in id's and names):

```
<div class="x" id="waistBox">
    <div class="measureCol measureColLeft">
        <span class="measureHeader">Waist</span>
        <div class="measureDescription">
            Surround your waist with the tape measure at the height
            you are most comfortable wearing your pants. Adjust the
            tape measure to your desired snugness, as your purchase
            waist will match this measurement exactly (e.g. 34.75
            inches).
        </div>
        <div class="measureValue">
            <input type="text" name="waist" value = "1" id="waistInput" class="editMeasureInfo"/>
            <i>inches</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="measureCol measureColRight">
        <div class="measureVideoContainer">
            <img src="../../images/Measure_Video.PNG" class="measureVideo" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery function:

```
function change_measurement_display(oldDisp, newDisp) {
    var oldBox = '#' + oldDisp + 'Box';
    var newBox = '#' + newDisp + 'Box';

    $(oldBox).hide('slide', {
        direction : 'right'
    }, 500);
    $(newBox).show('slide', {
        direction : 'right'
    }, 500); 


}
```

Comment: could you post the relevant code or make a fiddle please, much easier then having us dig through your source code which will change over time, helps the answer stay relevant to future readers of the thread :)  Thanks.

Comment: Hey @FireCrakcer37, the reason I didn't make/link to a Fiddle is because the functionality worked on the fiddle when it was set to No wrap - in <head>, but I couldn't get it to work on the native site. The site that I linked is just a static test site to display the functionality. I will post the relevant code.

Answer (score 12):

You want to use 'effect' instead of 'hide'

> $(oldBox).effect('slide', { direction: 'right', mode: 'show' }, 500);
>
> $(newBox).effect('slide', { direction: 'right', mode: 'hide' }, 500);

Comment: Tried this, didn't work :(

Comment: I had to remove the delay and it worked for me, the 500

Comment: You can add `duration:500` as option in the object parameter.

Comment: @RTF you are right - $(oldBox).effect('slide', {direction: 'right', duration: 1000}); is working fine.