# Javascript/jQuery : Creating a 'Powered By' slideout for footer logo on websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I found a jsfiddle that did something similar to what I wanted to do.  The modified version is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/479/ and it works on the jsfiddle.  I copied the code to my site, changed the id's and now, it doesn't appear to be working.  Below is the code located on my website.  I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.3 on my site.  Any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#footer_logo').hover(function(){
        if ($('#powered_by').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#powered_by').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
       } else {
            $('#powered_by').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <img src="img.png" width="63" height="25" id="footer_logo"/>
  <div id="powered_by" width="100px"/>Powered By: </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer_logo {
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#powered_by {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ff0000;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/7m7uK/480/) and its working well. If the issue still persist check this SO post: [JQuery UI show/slide not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473798/jquery-ui-show-slide-not-working-correctly), maybe their solution can help.

You want to show `#powered_by` when you hover-in, then hide it when the you hover-out, right?

I looked into your code and it's not how you properly want it to behave. For example if you hover-in, the element slides, but when you hover-out then hover-in again without letting it finish hiding, the hovering execution will be reversed.

It will be more efficient if you do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#footer_logo').hover(function(){
    //hover-in 
    $('#powered_by').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
},function(){
    //hover-out 
    $('#powered_by').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
});
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/7m7uK/481/).

Or with pure jQuery: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/FVa69/1/)

Comment: I included my jquery and jquery UI with wrong url path.  But I do like your solution, and I appreciate your contribution.  It works like a charm!

Comment: Found that the javascript version does something wierd.  If I move over the section multiple times, it basically counts how many times the mouse goes over the section, and goes in and out that many times.  How can I fix that?  I don't want it to do that?  I love how the jquery one works; however, can't set {overflow-x:hidden;} because of how I am using this.

Comment: You need to put [**stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before animate: `$(selector).stop().animate()`. I see, if there's a conflict by setting `overflow-x:hidden;` on the body. Then you can switch to animate `width` works same way. Here see this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/FVa69/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FVa69/3/ - Worked on jsfiddle so I checked it on my site and it doesn't work.  I am pasting my code below for the script, does it appear to be right? (I added a container around the entire thing so if the mouse moved over the powered by text it would stay out)  `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var $pBy = $('#powered_by'),
    w = $pBy.width();
$pBy.width(0)
$('#footer_logo_container').hover(function(){
    $pBy.stop(true).animate({width: w},'slow');    
},function(){
    $pBy.stop(true).animate({width: 0},'slow');
});
});
</script>`